# ImportError: cannot import name 'RandomizedLogisticRegression'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to import

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RandomizedLogisticRegression
```

but in return I get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'RandomizedLogisticRegression'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linear_model.RandomizedLogisticRegression` and `linear_model.RandomizedLasso` were deprecated in scikit-learn 0.19 and removed in 0.21.  See the [release notes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.19.html#version-0-19) and related [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8995).